# How can i parse json in c# with newtonjson?

Tags: c#, json

I'm new in c# and have this json string:

```
"{\"Result\":0,\"Packages\":[{\"Count\":5.0,\"Price\":100000},{\"Count\":10.0,\"Price\":170000},{\"Count\":20.0,\"Price\":300000},{\"Count\":50.0,\"Price\":600000},{\"Count\":100.0,\"Price\":900000}],\"IsArbitrary\":true}"
```

try parse that string with this code:

```
dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(html);
```

but i want access to for example array index zero or array index one,how can i write code for that purpose?thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `dynamic` unless there is no other option to solve your problem. Here is how you can create a type to map your data:

```
private struct DataHolder
{
    public decimal result { set; get; }
    public Package[] Packages { set; get; }
    public bool IsArbitrary { set; get; }
}

private struct Package
{
    public decimal Count { set; get; }
    public decimal Price { set; get; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string html = "{\"Result\":0,\"Packages\":[{\"Count\":5.0,\"Price\":100000},{\"Count\":10.0,\"Price\":170000},{\"Count\":20.0,\"Price\":300000},{\"Count\":50.0,\"Price\":600000},{\"Count\":100.0,\"Price\":900000}],\"IsArbitrary\":true}";

    DataHolder data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataHolder>(html);

    foreach(var package in data.Packages)
    {
       // do something with package.Count or package.Price
    }
}
```

Then you have a static object where you can access `Packages` and loop over it.

Comment: thanks,that true,now how can i show user with for loop that data?